# css class definition preceded by */html

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have following css code

```
 * html .Wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

What is the effect of * and html in the css code above?

Comment: Seems like an old school IE7 CSS hack

Comment: @NickFury - Not the same, this is the selector, not a property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a hack to make your CSS compatible with the IE6 browser.

You can refer to more hack techniques for various IE versions from here: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: Beat me to it! I was *just* researching this stuff for my own web dev purposes. +1 for finding a link with more complete info than what I had found in my Googling. Apparently most of the Internet doesn't know about the `* html` hack.

Comment: @ajp15243..please upvote me too :)